# Ubuntu One-related question - How to share files securely?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, security, sync, cloud

I have procrastinated this question a lot because I know it is a complex and a "crossover". That's why I have hesitated if to ask it here, on Ask Ubuntu, or somewhere else, let's say, Freelancer or Workspace. But, I have decided in the end, I need technical solutions to my socio-professional problems.

So, let's get to the point. I've been working as an online shop administrator for my former boss. But, till now I was paid only with praises and thanks. When I have explicitly asked for my money, I was asked to give detailed "proofs" of my work. Giving the fact that, at the beginning of our collaboration, my ex-boss told me that he knows everything I do online, I find it very weird to be asked right now for "proofs". So, I believe now this is only one of his tactics to delay my payment or even to discourage me.

Anyway, luckily, I had the inspiration to install Ubuntu One and to synchronise my work folder. So, theoretically, I have most of my "evidence" online and I can send him the link to see it. But here is the hard part, and here I need your answer and advice.

I am new in this Linux world and I had a lot of headache to make Ubuntu One work (and I still can't make the right-click menu work all the time). And I am hesitant about sharing my precious work files to a person that might try to erase or alter them.

Giving these facts, here are my worries and questions:

- How can I share my folder (and its files and sub-folders) to my former boss in such a way that he cannot alter them?
- Does Ubuntu One show (to the person I share with) the hour and date of the synchronisation (or when I have uploaded the file online)?
- Does Ubuntu One have any bugs related to synchronisation? If so, how can I fix this? I mean that, long after synchronising (or directly uploading) a file/folder, I saw a message in the right-top part of the screen saying something like that "file blablah.jpg it is uploaded". How can taht be? I mean, if I synchronise file blablah.jpg on 1 September, how can I see the message about its synchronisation on 5 or 10 or 12 September? Shouldn't it happen instantly? How does it affects the date shown online? I need the read time dates to be shown, in order to convince my boss that my work was real. (And if I can't convince him, I need to convince the authorities if it is necessarily to go my issue further).
- What other security advices can you give me related to Ubuntu One?

Please, excuse the complexity of my question, but I really need an answer so I can then answer to my ex-boss. I also intend to continue to use Ubuntu One at work to upload my important files.

If my question is not clear enough, please, do ask me for further details. I look forward for your answers as I think they will be helpful for other newbies too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the security is concerned..Ubuntu One is very good cloud service.
Open Ubuntu One Application on your computer >>Go to "Share Links" tab and type the name of the file you want to share online. 
Chose the file and click on enable link. 
Now you can share that link by simply clicking "copy link" and paste where you want to share the file.
I am not sure about folders but files can be easily shared this way.

Comment: If you can't see the list of files there...type first few letters of the file name. You will see your files. And make sure your Ubuntu One is synchronized properly. And the files you want to share are in the Ubuntu One folder.

Comment: mnstalemate Thanks for the tip! But I am not sure if my Ubuntu One is synchronised properly, and this is what I wont to check, but I am not sure how to do it. Anyway, I did not know that files I wont to share should be on Ubuntu One folder. My work folder is somewhere in another folder which is in my Home folder. But when I did a check from my online account, I could see my work folder there. (I did the checking from another PC having another Linux distro running from a flash drive, if this information is of any use.) If the folder/file is not in U1 is it instantly uploaded in the cloud?

Comment: Yes...to share files via Ubuntu One..your files should be in Ubuntu One Folder. You can also "chose" a particular folder to synchronize with your cloud.

Comment: mnstalemate So, should I understand that I can keep my work folder outside Ubuntu One and continue to synchronise it from there? Another question is: is it safe to share that folder? I mean that I wont the person I share with to only be able to see the content of the folder, but not to be able to alter it. I don't wont him to delete files or to re-edit them. In short, I wont the content of the folder to be read-only. How can I do that? How can I prevent abuses from the persons I share with? Is any such danger?

Comment: No..they can't alter the files. They can only see the shared files.

Comment: And there will always be an original copy with you. As you already know that every file has a timestamp on it, which identifies it's date of modification.